# Clarifying weird integral notation

Tags: integration, measure-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-integral

I would like your help to understand the following notation for integrals which I have never seen. Consider an integral
$$
\int_{a}^b 3 \text{ }d X
$$
where $X$ is a random variable. What does this mean $d X$? Is this a Lebesgue integral?

Comment: I guess that $X$ is an Itô process, so it should be an [Itô integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus)

Comment: In what context did you see this in?